# Why can't I specify a special geomfield using ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

my command like this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GEOJSON" -geomfield "the_geom" /Users/ziwen/work/test/ttt.geojson "PG:host=localhost dbname=g-default user=postgres password=xxxxxx"  -sql "select * from data.city"
```

table city has two geomfield "geom","the_geom" I use -geomfield to specify,but it doesn't work

Comment: Please never just say "*but it doesn't work*". Can you edit your question and add details about what *does* happen when your run that command (any error messages, unexpected results) and what version of GDAL you use.  The [help page](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) specifies OGR 1.11 or greater is required to use the `-geomfield` argument.

Comment: By reading the documentation https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html that option is not meant for that purpose `-geomfield field:    (OGR >= 1.11) Name of the geometry field on which the spatial filter operates on.`. Your query `select *`selects both geometries but GeoJSON format can only take one.

Comment: It can output a geojson file normally. But it always outputs the first geometry field, even I specify `-geomfield`. So how does the `-geomfield` work?

Comment: What is written into the documentation means that -geomfield defines which geometry to use if you apply spatial filter, for example by adding -spat parameter into your ogr2ogr command. Select your second geometry with enhanced SQL `select the_geom, attribute1, attribute 2 from data.city`.

Comment: If the SQL above does not work, add also `-dialect SQLite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **-geomfield** parameter, as described in the documentation https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html, defines which geometry is used when spatial filters are applied. Spatial filters are applied when **-spat** parameter or some of the clipping options are used. **-geomfield** option does not have any effect on which fields from the data will be selected. In your case because you do not use spatial filters in your ogr2ogr command this parameter does nothing.

In your ogr2ogr command the data is selected with SQL sentense `select * from data.city`. It selects all the fields, including both of your geometry fields. Both fields are also written to output if the format supports multiple geometries. You can test that for example with GML (**-f GML**).

GeoJSON supports only one geometry per feature and therefore, in case of multiple geometries, GDAL writes the first geometry which is the default geometry into the output just as you have noticed. For using some other geometry you must explicitly select it and that can be done with the **-sql** parameter.

The following command will write the "the_geom" geometry into your GeoJSON. Notice that you must also include all the attribute fields into the query because the "select *" shortcut cannot be used.

```
ogr2ogr -f "GEOJSON" /Users/ziwen/work/test/ttt.geojson "PG:host=localhost dbname=g-default user=postgres password=xxxxxx"  -sql "select the_geom, attribute1, attribute2 from data.city"
```

I tested that the command works with GDAL 2.4.0dev.